# UV Unwrap Face Sequence Messed up

Tags: uv

[image][image]So i just made a house wooden siding using planes, when i tried to uv unwrap it, the sequence of the face is messed up and it really annoying when i want to texture paint in blender, because whenever i paint, the paint always appear in another sides & when i wanted to add a texture, it's really messed up, it's hard to explain it so i'm gonna attach screenshot below, thank you so much

Comment: Hello have you checked the faces normal?

Comment: normals checked, everything is fine, that is why i'm so confused XD

Comment: could you please share your file (don't forget to pack your image, File > External Data > Pack Resources)? https://blend-exchange.com/